# Is it the right time to add `atomic-swaps` tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

There is already [one question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/13272/why-was-i-refunded-in-this-atompic-swap) in need of such a tag.
It is also worth considering adding a more specific tag, much like [xmrig](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xmrig) has its own tag,
**xmr-btc-swap** might have its own as well. The latter would refer specifically to [this software](https://github.com/comit-network/xmr-btc-swap).